# linear correlation in N-Dimensional sample

Tags: correlation, scipy

I've an N-dimensional sample linearly correlated to each other in pairs. That is, every event includes N variables, and every variable is a predictor to all the other (or, in other words, putting the sample on a timeline plots, all the graphs, with some offset, behaves in unison).

How do I represent this relation? How do I calculate it? And finally, given a new event, how do I calculate it's distance from the prediction?

UPDATE (giving some context, and what I'm trying to achieve):
Assume the sample data plotted on the graphs below. As you can see, each event has 4 variables (s1, s2, s3, and s4), which are strongly related to each other. Plotting any two series (e.g. s1 vs. s2) shows a very nice linear correlation. 
So, given all the data, I would like to:

1. Somehow represent this relationship. For example (and I'm totally out of my field here), I would assume, that in a 4-dimensional linear space, all events fall in a single line.
2. More importantly, given a new event (x1, x2, x3, x4), I would like to know "how far" it is from the prediction. E.g. if the solution is to draw this line on the N-dimensional space, I would like to get the euclidean distance between the new point and this line.

[image: sample data of 20 events, linearly related to each other]

Comment: Can you give us some more context about the problem and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Because (a) you are not using the term "event" according to its standard meaning in statistics and (b) you seem to be using it in more than one sense in this question, could you please provide a definition or characterization of what you mean by this term?

Comment: Thank you @whuber. Apology for not being familiar with the terms. Every few minutes I'm getting a measurement from 4 different sensors (total of 4 values). I used the term "event" to describe this vector of 4 values. Overall, in the plot above, I'm showing 20 such events. 
If I did a scatter of s1 and s2 (ignoring the timeline), it is easy to see they are linearly related (coveriance almost 1).

Comment: A fairly standard term is "observation."  Shall we take it that your question generally is about $N$ sensors and your example is a case with $N=4$?

Comment: Yes. thank you. I now realize the term is observation. And yes. In my example N=4, although, although in my real application N is up to 30.